# running `sudo apt-get autoremove` launches phpmyadmin configuration wizard

Tags: apt, lamp, phpmyadmin

I had a failed installation of phpmyadmin.

Now, I'm trying to completely uninstall Apache, MySQL, PHP, and phpmyadmin in order to start over and try again.

I'm following some online guides to do so. However, whenever I run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up the last few things, I get the phpmyadmin configuration wizard.

[image: phpmyadmin configuration]

No matter what selections I choose in the wizard, the configuration inevitably fails.

My goal is *not* to configure phpmyadmin. My goal is to *remove* phpmyadmin, along with Apache, MySQL, and PHP. But it won't let me. What do I do?

Comment: *"My goal is to remove phpmyadmin"* - did you run `sudo apt remove phpmyadmin`? You can also use `purge` instead of `remove` to also remove configs and other files related to the package.

Comment:  Yep that fixed it. I'd forgotten to try the obvious before posting the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sudo apt autoremove`, use `sudo apt remove packagename` or `sudo apt purge packagename` if you are trying to uninstall a particular package.

The difference between `remove` and `purge` in `apt` is that `purge` also removes configuration files and other files related to the package.

Examples:

```
sudo apt remove phpmyadmin
```

OR

```
sudo apt purge phpmyadmin
```